# "ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported."

Tags: asp.net, oracle, wcf, iis

I am trying to understand why the same C# Oracle access code works under VS2010 environment but not under IIS.

I am building a web service to access Oracle 9.2 database on the remote machine. The web service must be hosted in the IIS under Windows 2003 machine. The same machine is hosting Oracle 9.2 database.

The web service must be compiled for x86 CPU because of Windows 2003 that is 32-bit architecture. 
My Visual Studio project is WCF Application.

When I run the service under ASP.NET Development Server everything works fine. The database is connected and all CRUD operations are possible.

When I deploy everything under IIS on my machine or any other machine the I am getting **"ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported."** at the time of connecting.

I supposed it is some kind of permission problem so I run the service under special Application Pool with LocalSystem account. I even gave to the Oracle client folder installed on my machine Full Control permissions for IIS users but this should not be needed because of LocalSystem account.

Anyway I tried and nothing. It is always the same error.

What could be the reason ?

Comment: It's wierd that it works in ASP.NET Development Server and not works in IIS on the _same_ machine. But in general problem is incompatibility between ODP.NET and Oracle(e.g. version 12 of ODP.NET, and version 9.2 of Oracle). Do you have multiple ODP.NET versions installed on the same machine(in GAC)?

Comment: No I do not have multiple ODP.NET versions. I installed only 11g that is suggested as version to work with Oracle 9.2. I believe it is related to some permissions on the Oracle Client folder.